# Triangular Matrices and Simple Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, projective-module

> Let $\Bbb{T}_n(k)=\{n \times n \text{ upper triangular matrices (which includes the diagonal entries)}\}$
>
> I want to first express $\Bbb{T}_{n}(k)$ (as a $\Bbb{T}(k)$-module) as a direct sum of projective and indecomposable modules. Then I want to write the Jordan-Hölder decomposition for each of those modules.

Let $Col(i) =$ { n x n matrices with zeros everywhere except for the ith column; in the ith column, we have zeros below the diagonal entry and possibly nonzero entries in the diagonal and above the diagonal}. So, for example, a $3 \times 3$ matrix in $ Col(2)$ looks like $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & a & 0 \\0 & b & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ for some $a,b$.

Obviously, for any $A \in \Bbb{T}_n(k)$, we can write $A$ as a sum of the elements from $Col(1),...,Col(n)$. So, for example,

$\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\0 & d & e \\0 & 0 & f \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & b & 0 \\0 & d & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & c \\0 & 0 & e \\0 & 0 & f \end{bmatrix}.$

Obviously $Col(i) \cap (\sum_{i \not= j} Col(j)) = \{0\}$.

So $\Bbb{T}_n(k) = Col(1) \oplus ... \oplus Col(n)$.

Every $Col(i)$ is free, where the basis element is the matrix with zeros everywhere except for the ith diagonal entry where we have 1. So, for example, for any random element $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & a & 0 \\0 & b & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \in Col(2)$, we get $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & a & 0 \\0 & b & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a & 0 \\0 & b & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

But free modules are projective, so each $Col(i)$ must be projective. They are also indecompomsable. If $Col(i) = P \oplus Q$, then $P \cap Q = \{0\}$. But then the basis element is either contained in $P$ or in $Q$. But the summand that contains the basis element contains all of $Col(i)$, so the other summand must be zero. So $Col(i)$ is indecomposable.

Now I have to write the Jordan-Holder decomposition for $Col(i)$, and this is where I started getting confused. For example, if we look at $Col(3)$ for the $3 \times 3$ matrices...we know that we have a submodule of $Col(3)$, which is the set of all matrices with zeros everywhere except for the first two rows of the third column. And a submodule of that is the set of all matrices with zeros everywhere except for the first row of the third column. So...

$ \langle \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \rangle \supsetneqq \langle \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \rangle \supsetneqq \langle \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \rangle \supsetneqq 0$.

The problem here is that the quotients are not modules. For instance if we look at $\langle \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \rangle / \langle \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \rangle$, we get matrices with zeros everywhere except for the entry in the 3rd row and the 3rd column...but this set of matrices is not closed under scalar multiplication. So I must be doing something wrong, but I can't really see it...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Great job writing up the question. The post contained a lot of good work, led to a lot of teachable points, and hopefully left you with  some impressions and ideas that will stick with you :) Posts that are just problem statements allow none of this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R:=\Bbb T_n(k)$.

### Problem spot 1

> *Every $Col(i)$ is free*

No, while they are certainly free $k$ modules, they are not free $R$ modules. For one thing $R$ is $n(n+1)/2$ dimensional, while one of those column left ideals is never more than $n$ dimensional, so it's impossible for a left ideal to be isomorphic to copies of $R$.

However, as you noted, the $Col(i)$ are all *direct summands of $R$*, and so they are projective modules by virtue of being direct summands of the free module $_RR$.

### Problem spot 2

> *They are also indecompomsable. If Col(i)=P⊕Q, then P∩Q={0}. But then the basis element is either contained in P or in Q. But the summand that contains the basis element contains all of Col(i), so the other summand must be zero. So Col(i) is indecomposable.*

I have a hard time following this, and it seems like it is still based on the misapprehension that the column ideals are free. (*Added later*: We discovered in the comments that the root of the problem is that Artus was using the basis definition of "free module," but did not notice that the basis elements s/he was looking at were not $R$ independent. **Mini problem spot:** Even if $P\oplus Q\cong R$, there is no reason to expect that a basis element of $P\oplus Q$ must be contained in $P$ or contained in $Q$, as you tried above. In fact, if $P$ and $Q$ are nonzero, that will *never* happen. If the generator were in $P$, its span would be trapped in $P$. How would it generate all of $P\oplus Q$?)

It is very easy to see that the column ideals are irreducible if you first prove this useful lemma, which I should leave up to you:

### Lemma

> The submodules of $Col(i)$ are linearly ordered, and they are exactly what you expect them to be: you get them by turning zeroing out coordinates in the column one at a time from the bottom up.

For example, the left ideals in $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&k\\0&0&k\\0&0&k\end{bmatrix}$ are $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&k\\0&0&k\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&k\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Using this, it's obvious $Col(i)$ is indecomposable: the intersection of two nonzero submodules is always the smaller submodule in the chain of submodules.

This lemma also automatically gives you the Jordan-Holder decomposition! When the submodules are in a chain, the decomposition is unique! To show that the factor modules are indeed simple, just note that their $k$ dimension is $1$, and you can't get a nonzero module which is smaller.

---

Your composition series is perfect!

### Problem spot 3

You're misidentifying the quotient with a subset of R. It isn't a set of matrices, it's a set of cosets of the left ideal. You're right that you can pick a set of coset representatives that is nonzero only on the 3-3 entry, but those aren't the elements of the quotient. Coset representatives are rarely closed under addition. The *cosets* are closed under addition and left multiplication by R though.

Comment: I have one more question (if you don't mind). Just to be sure...are you saying my Jordan Hölder decomposition is right or wrong? I'm just asking because you didn't explicitely say that. Anyways, thanks for answering.

Comment: @Artus you're right, I padded the matrices with zeros to make it correct.

Comment: @Artus it looks like you are confusing "free" with "cyclic". These things are completely different. It is indeed cyclic. A free module is a direct sum of copies of R . R has k dimension much greater than n, but all of the left ideals you are looking at have k dimension less than n. That is why it's impossible for a finite dimensional algebra to have a proper left ideal that's free.

Comment: @Artus I added details for those concerns. Enjoy!

Comment: @rschwied Thanks, but I just have one more question...a free module is a module with a basis, right? But there is only one generating element (since its cyclic), and the only way we can get zero is by multiplying the generating element by the zero matrix in $R$. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but this module is finitely generated by one element, and this element is linearly independent. Isn't that the definition of basis?

Comment: @Artus yes, that is a definition of free, but these ideals fail this definition because you **cannot find R independent generators**. Whatever generator x you pick, I can show you there exists a nonzero y such that yx=0.

Comment: @Artus I realize it's tempting to think a single element must be linearly independent...  But this isn't true for general rings! :) I think we finally found the misconception that was blocking you.

Comment: @Artus I added one more thing about a small problem that I noticed while rereading your solution. Let me know if I need to clarify it. Thanks for suggesting improvements above, and I'm glad the solution was helpful!